# Dragon Dictate (or Mavericks Dictation): How do they work? Do they have an API?

Tags: voice-dictation

This paper (http://qh.antenna.nl/unimacro/implementation_and_acceptance_of_natlink.pdf) explains how NatLink was made, a Python interface to Dragon NaturallySpeaking, on Windows. NaturallySpeaking exposes a COM interface.

For Mac, does Dictate expose any interface?

I'd like to use it for programming, for which I need to script it. Without buying Windows, and another Dragon product, and VMWare, and setting it all up, etc.

Dragon is more accurate than Dictation, but I really need to have control of the grammar and stuff, like this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8SkdfdXWYaI).

(I'd like an HTTP API, but I'll take any API. It's 2014.)

I have burning wrist pain, and dictation is the one thing that has given me hope in the past few months. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

http://voicecode.io does exactly what you are describing here and is for Mac. It allows you to extend its grammar resulting in very efficient voice control for programmers.

*disclaimer - I'm the creator of VoiceCode

Comment: http://voicecode.io/details

Comment: (1) this looks great. (2) $300 is a lot of money, given that Dictate is over $100 too. given that I have RSI, I'd gladly pay twice that if it did everything I wanted too. however, NatLink has over a decade of development/community, and is free. also, I've used both Dictate and DNS. Dictate is the worst software I have ever used. beyond a bad API, it crashes on me every hour, has weird modefulness that causes infinite loops searching a nonstandard application for text, and seems to me less accurate than DNS. does your product address this, or can you show that it's fixable?

Comment: (3) can you show me the grammars that let you dictate in your demo (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FlluHR6pgHc)? the site said there is a scripting language, perhaps like Vocola. I would prefer programming in a programming language, like Python with NatLink, unless the DSL is really good. (4) as for bash scripts and AppleScript, my own little tests showed that there was too much overhead to make those calls. unless there's some running process that can interpret Bash/AppleScript. Is this the case with your product?

Comment: also, I'm really happy that people like you are working on voice control. I mean, isn't it the third millennium already!?